# How to get custom post type post id from slug?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to grab the custom post type post id just only from slug?

As much i know we can get from id by using title. But there can be same title in a custom post type so as slugs are unique is it possible???

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) - don't let the name fool you, third argument is the post type:

```
if ( $post = get_page_by_path( 'the_slug', OBJECT, 'post_type' ) )
    $id = $post->ID;
else
    $id = 0;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you just want the post id this will do the trick in one line.

```
url_to_postid( site_url('the_slug') );
```

Comment: The `url_to_postid` is a very flexible function: you can pass in any kind of permalink/full URL and get the most accurate post-ID for that URL. However, because of the flexible usage it's quite slow (esp. with lot of endpoints/post-types).
If you only pass in a slug for a specific post type, it's a lot faster to use `get_page_by_path()`

Comment: Good solution for when you're not sure of the post type.

Answer (score 8):

If you wait a couple of days, and upgrade to [Wordpress 4.4](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.4) which will be released the 8th of December (*AFAIK*), you can use the new `post_name__in` parameter in `WP_Query` which takes an array of slugs

### EXAMPLE

If you need the complete post object

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_name__in'  => ['post-slug']
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
var_dump( $q );
```

If you only need the ID

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_name__in'  => ['post-slug'],
    'fields'         => 'ids' 
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
var_dump( $q );
```

Comment: Nice, but probably a bit intensive to get one post by slug? Why did they add that feature!?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Mighty be a bit intensive yes, haven't really tested performance on this, just added as means of an alternative ;-). As to why, I really do not know, looks like one of those nice-to-have-unnecessary things that WordPress is so famous for. The naming convention, IMHO, is also wrong, just like the `post_name` property and `category_name` parameter, which should have been `slug` and not `name`

Comment: Nice :)  wow actually for me its nice update :)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic There is no time difference between my method and your method. I constantly get between 0.002 and 0.005 seconds to run each of our queries. Also, both methods run 1 query only. ;-)

Comment: When I suggested `get_page_by_path` is more performant I just meant PHP has less work to do (a bit of argument parsing and an SQL query) compared to `WP_Query` (which involves multiple object instantiation and running over many filters/actions/arguments). Actual timings rarely tend to illustrate unless we simulate 1000's of ops. But worth knowing in the real-world it ultimately makes no difference ;)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic *I just meant PHP has less work to do* - yes, for sure, totally agree. It is just always nice to know alternatives (*although it might sometime not be the best*) and having some kind of benchmarks. Enjoy ;-)